# Can i make a shell script executable in Mac without chmod stuff?

Tags: shell, executable

I have seen that i can use **chmod +x** command in Mac to make a shell script executable. This works fine, but i have noticed that i have to do the same thing every time this shell script file is copied to another Mac computer.

Is there a way to make the shell script executable by default when double clicked, without such command ... As the shell script file will be given to many users, and doing this will be hard for some of them ?

Best regards.

Comment: How are you copying the file so that the execute permissions are lost?  Maybe you should use an alternative technique.

Comment: @Jonathan: It is a package ... a jar file containing a group of files, and one of them is that shell file(Before adding it to the jar i've set its permission to be executable). When i extracted the files and tried to run the shell file it failed.

Answer (score 1):

If you pack your whole program in a .tar file (or in a .tar.gz-file, which is the same, but compressed), the executable-"permission" will be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Give it the '.command' extension and it can be executed from the Finder.

Comment: .. I am already doing so, but it does not execute by default. It shows message: "The file could not be executed because you do not have appropriate access privileges"